# how to configure ingress to direct traffic to an https backend ... with istio ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

Hi i have deployed elastic search in Kubernetes with a self-signed certificate I want expose elastic search URL but am able to do nginx ingress but not successful with istio can any one explained how to do that
this is the virtual service

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - elasticsearch.domain.com
  gateways:
    - monitor-gateway
  http:
    - match:
      - port: 443
      route:
      - destination:
          host: elasticsearch.monitor.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 9200
```

gateway

```
# Source: istio-ingress/templates/gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: monitor-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    app: istio-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: istio-ingress
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.15.3
    helm.sh/chart: gateway-1.15.3
    istio: ingress
spec:
    selector:
      istio: ingress
    servers:
    - hosts:
      - '*'
      port:
        name: http
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
    - hosts:
      - '*'
      port:
        name: https
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTP
    - hosts:
      - '*'
      port:
        name: tpc
        number: 15021
        protocol: TCP
```

Comment: could you please share the yaml of istio what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

By adding below destination Rule i resloved

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: elasticsearch.monitor.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 9200
      tls:
        clientCertificate: /etc/istio/ingress/ca.cert
        mode: SIMPLE
        privateKey: /etc/istio/ingress/tls.key
```